# Casting with unknown class

Tags: java, casting

I need to cast a value by an unknown class name. Here is an example of what I need to do :

```
Filter filter = session.getFilter(aName);
for (Object key :filter.getFilterDefinition().getParameterTypes().keySet() ){
filter.setParameter("param1",filter.getFilterDefinition().getParameterType(key.toString()).getReturnedClass()) 
value )
}
```

So as you can see, I need to cast with the parameter type of the map key

Is it possible? Othewise, how can I do such a cast.

thanks

Comment: No, is not possible. You could use `instanceof` operator to check if the object reference is from certain class.

Comment: Why would you want to cast it to something unknown, and then assign it to a `String` reference? This makes no sense.

Comment: Might one inquire as to the point of doing this, if you could?

Comment: It will be gr8 to specify what you will have as a left hand side of `=` in `= (o.getClass())o;` ?

Comment: If the class is unknown, you cannot declare your variable with it's type.  I mistakenly answered with [`Class#cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) but this cannot be used because it simply returns the parameter type of the `Class` object, so this approach cannot work with an unknown class.

Comment: @Keppil I understood the `String` example as simply a poor example of casting to an unknown class.  The question would benefit from a clearer example, possibly along the lines of `Object o = ...; A a = (A.class) o;` but I'm weary of making such a large edit.

Comment: The only sensible approach is to cast to the type of the receiver.  This will fail, with a ClassCastException, if the value is not of the receiver's class (or a suitable subclass).

Comment: @Keppil I mentioned a simple use case. My need is to cast a value while passing it as a parameter but I do not have any idea about the class to cast with

Comment: It would be better for all readers if you show the functional requirement and the proposed technical solution.

Comment: But the parameter has a fixed type.

Comment: @Issam: Please edit to a use case that at least makes sense then, to give us an idea where you are going with this.

Comment: the parameter has as type : Object so it need to be cast

Comment: Now, why you need to do this? What's the functional requirement?

Comment: If Parameter has type `Object` you `dont need to cast`. DO you get any compile /runtime error if you proceed further without casting?

Comment: The functional requirement is that the value type is mapped to the filter one I need to cast it in order to pass the parameter correctly

Comment: But `Filter#setParameter` already accepts `Object` and `Object`. There's no sense on doing a type cast here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.  But if you have an Object myObject, and you have the name of the class you want to cast it to in a String

```
String className = "com.mycompany.Foo";
Class<T> c = Class.forName(className);
T castToT = c.cast(myObject);
```

This only seems useful if you know in advance that className is a subclass of some class or interface T.  Cause otherwise T has to be Object and you are doing a lot of work for nothing.

Comment: That's what I need thank you !!
Well, `anInstance.getClass().cast(anotherInstance)` works fine without compilation or runttime error

Comment: @Issam the fact that compiles doesn't mean it will do what you expect...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it does what I expect functionnally ;-)

Comment: But in the above example the runtime type of `T` is `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

Casting is by definition operation that "transforms" type to another at compile time, so the type written in brackets must be written hard coded. Therefore operation `(o.getClass())obj` does not make any sense.

Moreover class you cast to must be assignable to the type written at the left side of the assignment. Therefore expression:

`OneClass o = (OtherClass)obj;`

can be valid only if `OneClass` is assignable from `OtherClass`.

And the third point. `o.getClass()` returns class of `o`. Casting of object of certain class to the same class does not make any sense.

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
// obj is an instance of MyClass
```

Attempt to peform this casting:

`(MyClass)obj`

will product compilation warning.

I hope my explanations help. I believe that you actually wanted to ask other question that brought you to this one. I think that you should ask the first question you had. Probably community will be able to help you to understand your problem deeper and find better solution.

Comment: Why the type written in brackets must be hard coded ? writing `OtherClass` or `otherInstance.getClass()` are not equivalent ? I'm sure that the operation `getClass()` returns the required type

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell the use case where you need to do this? Are you trying to use this strategy to cast the references at runtime? Please make sure you are not type casting unrelated types.

Applications using this kind of strategy are usually are not easy to maintain and debug.

Comment: I need to have 50 reputation score to move it to comments. If this is correct then if someone can help moving it to comments section. I wanted to add to comments only.